# XmlSerializer Convert all children to list or match any Name [XmlElement(ElementName = "*")]

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlserializer

Is there an experession like this [XmlElement(ElementName = "*")] in XmlSerializer. I mean just for a particular level in an XML structure.

I have the following XML element structure;

```
<AirlineList>
    <AQR>...</AQR>
    <ABA>...</ABA>
    <AAI>...</AAI>
    <A9W>...</A9W>
    <AVS>...</AVS>
    <AAF>...</AAF>
    <AEY>...</AEY>
    <ALH>...</ALH>
    <AQF>...</AQF>
</AirlineList>
```

The xml structure for the children elements is all the same - they just happen to have different tag names. Is there a way to covert these elements into a list of AirlineList but using the same object type. i.e; Airline such that I get;

```
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AirlineList")]
    public AirlineList List<Airline> { get; set; }
```

At the moment I have to use this;

```
public class AirlineList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AQR")]
    public List<AQR> AQR { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ABA")]
    public List<ABA> ABA { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AAI")]
    public List<AAI> AAI { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "A9W")]
    public List<A9W> A9W { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AVS")]
    public List<AVS> AVS { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AAF")]
    public List<AAF> AAF { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AEY")]
    public List<AEY> AEY { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ALH")]
    public List<ALH> ALH { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AQF")]
    public List<AQF> AQF { get; set; }
}
```

I want to covert this into a list of Airline

Comment: Could you change the XML structure so that each element was like <Airline Name="AQR"/> ?

Comment: Yes, I could. I just wanted to see if I could match any element using [XmlElement]